# How to hide sidebar in React using Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-applications, antd

I'm trying to do a sidebar that hides on the clicking of an icon in the navigation bar. And I don't want to use classes, maybe I'm wrong doing it this way, but I want to keep it as much as possible. I've got an error that says:

> (property) collapsed: boolean ';' expected.ts(1005)

In the const toggle:

```
const state = {
    collapsed: true
  };

const toggle = () => {
    state.collapsed: !state.collapsed
};


const Sidebar = () => {

  return (
    <Layout.Sider collapsed={state.collapsed} style={{ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0' }}>
     ...
    </Layout.Sider>
  )
}
```

In the navigation bar I got this:

```
<Button
            type="primary"
            shape="circle"
            icon="user"
            size={'small'}
            style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
            onClick={() => toggle}
          />
```

My layout:

```
const Layout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <AntdLayout>
      <AntdLayout>
        <Header />
      </AntdLayout>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <Sidebar />
    </AntdLayout>
  )
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things what I found as an issue in your code. If you have functional component, you can use `useState` for updating `boolean` state. The other one is how you use `onClick={() => toggle}`, technically you are not calling the function, just returning.

I think you can try the following - creating a boolean variable with state hook:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
   const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);

   return (
      <Layout.Sider collapsed={state.collapsed} style={{ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0' }}>
         ...
      </Layout.Sider>
   )
}
```

And in the button, you can use as the following - toggling the value of `collapsed` variable:

```
<Button type="primary"
        shape="circle"
        icon="user"
        size={'small'}
        style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
        onClick={() => setCollapsed(!collapsed)} />
```

Read further here:

1. [State hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
2. [Function and Class components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

If you are interested in further, I have prepared earlier a repository on GitHub to present toggling elements in class, functional or styled components. Find it here: [norbitrial/react-toogle-class-on-click](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-toogle-class-on-click)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, I see. But the button is in the Header and setCollapse is only usable inside the Sider component. So what should I do to make that method visible?

Comment: Oh, then there are two ways to handle the scenario, either create a state variable in the parent and pass it down through `props` to child component or create a store for the application - possibly Redux - which will help you access the `collapsed` state variable from any component. If the situation is not complex - just like what you mentioned - I would go with the `props` option.